# Select query on postgresql database result is empty. Am I using wrong logic?

Tags: postgresql, visual-c++, c++-cli, npgsql

I am using Npgsql for postgresql in C++/CLI. So, the problem is, I have a db on my computer, and I am trying to select some of data from it's "movies" table. I already entered some data inside it, so I know that it has some data. But when I try to select some of them, answer to my query is empty. My code is like below:

```
public: string* SelectData(string* torrent)  
        {  
            conn->Open();
            String ^ query = "SELECT title, director, actors, genre FROM movies";
            Npgsql::NpgsqlCommand ^ command = gcnew NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
            try{
                Npgsql::NpgsqlDataReader ^ dr = command->ExecuteReader();
                for (int i = 0; i < N_TORRENT; i++)
                {
                    if(dr->Read())
                    {
                        string std1 = toStandardString((String^)dr[0]);
                        string std2 = toStandardString((String^)dr[1]);
                        string std3 = toStandardString((String^)dr[2]);
                        string std4 = toStandardString((String^)dr[3]);
                        torrent[i] = std1 + " " + std2 + " " + std3 + " " + std4;
                    }
                } 
                return torrent;
            }  
            finally{  
                conn->Close();  
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide some log?

Comment: I only have Output logs from the Visual Studio, and apparently they are not about database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For the ones who will look for this question's answer)
Problem solved when I changed my query and look for the "title" column that are not empty. But this is ridiculus, so I beleive the problem was about pgAdmin. Because my insert query was not working either, but I added "rowseffected" variable and it shows the effected row's number and looks like it is working. So the problem is probably about the pgAdmin.